# Do screen readers pay attention to CSS?

Tags: javascript, css, accessibility, less

Do screen readers just read content without paying attention to CSS?

My reason for asking is that I would like to use LESS.js for some of my CSS (so not all of it). As far as I'm concerned, users with JS disabled will get a basic experience anyway so they won't miss some of my presentational CSS.

However, what about Screen Readers... will they miss my extra CSS that's served via Javascript?

P.S. no compiler suggestions please, I'm not interested - they slow down my workflow.

Thanks

Comment: Depends on what *kind* of CSS, I guess. If it's just rounded edges and gradients, you probably won't have to worry

Comment: If you're doing something like `div:before { content: "It was the best of times, it was the best of times yada yada yada aydaa " }` and the reader doesn't parse css, then it's going to be "A Tale of **NO** Cities" instead.

Comment: I can't think of any existing screen reader that understands even aural stylesheets... not even JAWS, no. So much for standardizing aural styles in [CSS2.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/aural.html).

Comment: http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201111/screen_readers_and_css/

Comment: @BoltClock: the issue here is that the screenreader is not actually a user-agent/browser; it's just reading out what the underlying browser does, and the browser is rendering for a screen. A true speech-based browser might use an aural stylesheet, but currently none of the existing screenreaders follow that model.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that screenreaders are not necessarily speech based; some use Braille, or both Braille and speech; don't assume that "reader" means "voice" here. Even for voice-based ones, the user likely wants to leave their TTS settings as-is (often using a neutral sounding voice with speed turned up so fast that most people would not understand it at first listening!) and not have some page override those. Fundamentally, screenreader users are interacting with a desktop-based UI indirectly via speech/braille, not with a primary speech-based UI.

Comment: As for LESS.js, you can use it during development and switch for the generated CSS file when in production. Or you could use LessPHP (similar except that parameters in functions are separated by semicolons and not commas) and generate CSS server-side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're supposed to take cues from the CSS properties defined in the  [voice module](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-speech/) when figuring out how read CSS styled text.

> The aural rendering of a document combines speech synthesis (also known as "TTS", the acronym for "Text to Speech") and auditory icons (which we refer to as "audio cues" in this specification). The aural presentation of information is common amongst communities of users who are blind or visually-impaired. For instance, "screen readers" enable control of visual user-interfaces that would otherwise be inaccessible. There are other cases whereby listening to textual information (as opposed to reading it) is a necessity. Typical examples include in-car use of an e-book reader, industrial and medical documentation systems, home entertainment, helping users to learn reading, or supporting users who have reading difficulties (print disabilities).
>
> When it comes to documents, the quality of the speech rendition depends on the structure and semantics authored within the content itself. The CSS Speech module provides properties that enable authors to declaratively control presentational aspects of the aural dimension (e.g. TTS voice, pitch, rate, and volume levels). These style sheet properties can be used together with visual properties (mixed media), or as a complete aural alternative to a visual presentation.
>
> Content creators can conditionally include CSS properties dedicated to user-agents with text to speech synthesis capabilities, by specifying the "speech" media type via the media attribute of the link element, or with the @media at-rule, or within an @import statement. When doing so, the styles authored within the scope of such conditional statements are ignored by user-agents that do not support this module.

Comment: It seems like the general takeaway is that it's OK to have general CSS in my JS. If I need to specifically use the CSS speech module I'll put it in my main stylesheet (doubt the aural stuff will be complicated enough for me to use LESS with it anyway)

Comment: -1, because given the current way screenreaders work, CSS voice is simply not relevant to how screenreaders work today. Screenreaders are fundamentally not browsers or user-agents; rather they read out what the browser does, often accessing whatever is in the browser's DOM (either directly or via an accessibility API); as such, they are reading out content that is rendered/styled for a *display*, not voice. Finally, a screenreader may not even be voice-based at all, and may use braille for output to the user.

Comment: @BrendanMck, I don't know where you got the idea that I said that a screen reader is a browser.  I merely quoted CSS 3 which defines it thus '**"screen readers"** enable control of visual user-interfaces that would otherwise be inaccessible.'  As to the rest, yes, screen readers need not be aural and before there were good open-source browsers on all OSes were restricted to what plugin frameworks provided which could restrict computed style to media group visual, but that is not an inherent limitation of a screen reader and the CSS module quoted above makes the intent clear.

Comment: @MikeSamuel - "...CSS properties dedicated to *user-agents with text to speech synthesis capabilities*" is the part I was referring to. Regardless, this is a minor quibble; the real issue is that aural stylesheets are not used by any mainstream screenreader today; so while your answer may be useful at some point in the future, it doesn't address the OP's question regarding how the technology operates *today*.

Comment: @BrendanMcK, understood.  Thanks for explaining.  As one datapoint, [Aural CSS](http://lab.dotjay.co.uk/notes/css/aural-speech/) has a table at the end which says that Opera 9 supports quite a few, Firevox has partial support for a few and GW Micro has no plans to support aural CSS.

Answer (score 7):

The most important issue to understand here is that a screenreader is not a browser: it is an app that reads out the UI of other apps, either via speech, braille, some combination or the two - or possibly even some other means.

When reading the web, the screenreader doesn't actually load or parse HTML or CSS: the browser does that, and the screenreader reads out what gets displayed by the browser, typically by either accessing the underlying DOM directly (eg. on Win32 with IE, via the various IHTML* interfaces) or via an accessibility-related API.

(Note that this means that support can vary depending on the screenreader and browser combination; JAWS can work against IE or Firefox, but not currently Chrome, Opera or Safari; and might in some cases actually read things out differently against IE vs Firefox.)

Usually this means that screenreaders ignore most CSS - they pretty much ignore most formatting and layout and concentrate on content; but all modern screenreaders do take at least display: and visibility: into account, so they will not read out content that a sighted user would not see. For example, a screenreader would not want to read out "collapsed" text - until it was appropriate to do so. The key issue here is that these two CSS attributes actually have semantic meaning, so it's important for the screenreaders to convey that.

Since the screenreaders get these values typically from the DOM (either directly or indirectly), it doesn't matter whether they were set via inline styles, an external stylesheet, or at runtime via javascript.

--

A quick note on aural stylesheets: right now, they are simply not relevant at all to the screenreader scenario.

First, there's the issue that a screenreader user might not be using speech output in the first place.

Secondly, most screenreader users have their voice set to a very specific voice - typically a neutral one that the user can understand well at high speeds - and then they'll pump up the speed to a very fast speed that most folks won't be able to understand at all. The last thing a screenreader user wants is for some page to start overriding their voice settings.

This makes the screenreader experience fundamentally different from a speech-based UI (where an aural sheet might be appropriate). The UI is really still display-based; it just happens to be accessed by the user in an indirect manner; and that indirection might be via speech, or braille, or some combination. But you shouldn't have to care about that, so long as you have good semantic markup in your page in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no. CSS needs to be parsed for the screen reader to know whether or not to read an item. Items with `display: none` wont get read by a screen reader, however there are still other means of hiding content that can only be observed with a screen reader.

I highly recommend downloading a development copy of JAWS or Window Eyes and performing an actual usability test of your site.

Comment: Also suggest [NVDA](http://www.nvda-project.org/) as a screenreader to test with; it's free and open source - and gaining in popularity. JAWS costs about $800 or so, and while every pro design firm should have a copy available for their devs/designers to test against, NVDA is a good alternative for casual testing.

Comment: I also recommend NVDA for a screen reader test, however do note that JAWS doesn't work the same way; it has many additional features and scripting to provide access that NVDA might not have; the purpose of a screen reader is to "cheat" and provide as much access as possible to the end user, even in ways that work if the web page itself wasn't coded "properly". This is one reason our program avoids use of assistive technology for Section 508 inspection and instead relies upon tools like Web Accessibility Toolbars (that visually inspects the DOM). If it is coded properly, it should work.